# Use custom button as RideRequestButton Uber

Tags: uber-api

I'am using uber api for my app and specific ride request widget. I want to use my own custom button in place of Uber's RideRequestButton.

This is the static code for ride request button.

```
private RideRequestButton blackButton;

blackButton = (RideRequestButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_button_black);
blackButton.setRequestBehavior(new RideRequestActivityBehavior(this,WIDGET_REQUEST_CODE));
```

Is it possible to apply the function on my own button.?

Answer (score 1):

The customization options for the simple button is currently a color scheme, you can choose a white theme or a black theme. See the documentation for that here: https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk#ride-request-button

However, in the background, the button simply opens up a deeplink. If you would like you can just use that deeplink and create your own custom button on top of that. Please check out the documentation for the "requestride" method in the "RequestDeeplinkBehavior" class: https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/blob/master/rides-android/src/main/java/com/uber/sdk/android/rides/RequestDeeplinkBehavior.java

Comment: If the app is not installed in my phone than the deeplink redirect me to playstore. But I want to open the login page inside my app only.

Comment: @SavinSharma  `deeplink.execute()` does what you're saying. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where we have our own button but still we need to use Uber sdk, hope this might be of help. For details, refer docs [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction#standard-deep-links)

Build the session configuration using the keys from the dashboard.

```
SessionConfiguration sessionConfig = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .setServerToken(SERVER_TOKEN)
                .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
                .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .build();
```

Then set the ride parameters along with desired pickup and dropoff locations.

```
RideParameters rideParameters = new RideParameters.Builder()
                .setPickupLocation(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng), "Your location", "Current Address")
                .setDropoffLocation(Double.parseDouble(mEvent.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(mEvent.getLongitude()), mEvent.getName(), mEvent.getCity())
                .build();
```

Build the deeplink with the session configuration and ride parameters from above.

```
mDeepLink = new RideRequestDeeplink.Builder(getActivity())
                .setSessionConfiguration(sessionConfig)
                .setFallback(Deeplink.Fallback.APP_INSTALL)
                .setRideParameters(rideParameters)
                .build();
```

Finally get the uri from the deeplink and pass it as an intent.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mDeepLink.getUri()));
```

It will always open the app and If it's is not installed, redirect manually to play store.